# JS interval generation function with Moment.js: Unexpected output

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs

I've been working on a function that generates an array of ten Innings **(objects with beginning and end times)** through a loop. For example.

- The Game **starts** Monday at 12:00 AM, and **ends** Saturday at 12:00AM
- The Game is comprised of 10 **12-hour Innings**
- **Inning 1** starts Monday at 12:00 AM and ends 12:00PM the same day, when **Inning 2** begins.

You get the idea. Times are kept with [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

I've written the code that I expected to handle this, but the functionality is broken. See my function logic notes at bottom. Here is a [JSFiddle demonstrating the code and results](http://jsfiddle.net/LmuX6/7/), and here is the function:

---

```
//Define the Game's Time Frame

var Game = new Object(); // Object that holds all game data

var end = { // what time does the game end?
    "moment": moment().days(6).hour(0).minute(0).second(0)
};

var beginning = { // what time does the game start?
    "moment": moment().days(1).hour(0).minute(0).second(0)
};

// I'm going to over-do the commenting here for debugging:

// assign start and end times to each of 10 innings
function generateInnings() { 

    // create an inning object to assign start and end to
    var inning = new Object(); 

    // create array to assign each of 10 inning objects to
    Game.innings = new Array(); 

    // shortcut for calculating game time span
    var gameHours = 120; 

    // ten innings in a game. how many hours each?
    var inningHours = gameHours / 10; 

    // for 10 intervals of x, generate each inning
    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) { 

        //inning starts when?
        inning.start = beginning.moment.add("hours", (inningHours * x)); 

        // inning ends when?
        inning.end = inning.start.add("hours", inningHours);

        // attach inning object to Game.innings array
        Game.innings[x] = inning; 

        // JSFiddle Output
        log("Inning " + x + " Starts: " + inning.start.calendar()); 

        // JSFiddle Output
        log("Inning " + x + " Ends: " + inning.end.calendar()); 

    }

}

generateInnings();
```

---

**Result:**

- Inning 0 Starts: Last Monday at 12:00 PM
- Inning 0 Ends: Last Monday at 12:00 PM
- Inning 1 Starts: Last Tuesday at 12:00 PM
- Inning 1 Ends: Last Tuesday at 12:00 PM
- Inning 2 Starts: Last Thursday at 12:00 AM
- Inning 2 Ends: Last Thursday at 12:00 AM
- ... need we go further?

---

**What's causing this (very) incorrect output?**

---

Function logic (this is not code, but notes):

```
beginning = 12:00AM Mon

for (x=0;x<10;x++){ //do this x10

    start = beginning plus (12hrs * current loop interval)

    console.log("Inning" + current loop interval + " start: " + start);
}
```

---

for x = 0, start = beginning + (12 * 0) hours // = still Monday 12:00 **AM**

for x = 1, start = beginning + (12 * 1) hours // = Monday 12:00 **PM**

for x = 2, start = beginning + (12 * 2) hours // = Tuesday 12:00 **AM**

---

I thought I had built a pretty solid, fundamental function. I just can't see an issue in the logic, it must be the Moment syntax.

Comment: Moment [lists](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/range/) some very nice plugins for ranges. I especially like Twix. Why don't you consider using them?

Comment: Right, well I'm looking at twix, and I've already got the ranges set up with Moment. I think I see how I can use Twix next time to make the code smoother, but unfortunately the issue here doesn't seem to be range-related. Thanks for the mention though!

Comment: Anyone see anything here? I'm at a dead end without this one. It's almost certainly something with the Moment syntax, and no changes that I continue to make give me even close to expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

`inning.end = inning.start.add("hours", inningHours);`

The `add()` method does not return a value, but modifies it's own object, because [moments are mutable](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/).

Instead, do:

`inning.end = moment(inning.start).add("hours", inningHours);`